# How can I fade tabs in & out with the Twitter Bootstrap framework?

Tags: jquery, tabs, twitter-bootstrap

jQuery UI has the option to initialize tabs with the tabs set to fade in/out, like so:

```
$(".selector").tabs({ fx: { opacity: 'toggle' } });
```

Is something similar possible with the Twitter Bootstrap framework tabs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, but you could add your own, [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HubVW/10/)

```
$('.tabs').tabs()
    .bind('change', function (e) {
        $(this).next().hide().fadeIn();
    });
```

Comment: See Sanghyun's answer.  It's the correct way to do this.

Answer (score 65):

Both for Bootstrap 2 and 3, you can simply give your `.tab-pane` elements a `fade` class with `bootstrap-transition.js` loaded. No need to write a single line of your own  JavaScript code at all.

```
<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="home">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="messages">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="settings">...</div>
</div>
```

Code sample from [the official Twitter Bootstrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs-usage).

Comment: If we are going to give fade class to all of them it will hide the contents of all tabs.Answer will be at least one of the tab should have `in` after fade class written to work.

Comment: I believe this answer + @PHPSeeker's comment are the more adequate solutions to this problem, since they use the facilities provided by the framework and therefore better answer the question as stated (and, personally, the reference to `.in` saved me a lot of headache just now)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It also works in Bootstrap 3.

Comment: More specifically, the "fade in" must be in the active panel. I was silly enough to be confused about that for a few minutes.

Comment: Thanks for solution.